# switch statement in report builder 3.0 to compare list of values

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services

I need to use a switch statement in a SSRS report to display text depending on the value of 3 parameters.  The parameters are multi-valued and they have defaults set to 0 and 1.  So, if the parameter is set to 1, the text is shown.
This is my current switch statement:

```
=Switch(Parameters!NormalBirthWeight.Value(0) <> "0", "Normal Birth Weight", Parameters!LowBirthWeight.Value(0) <> "0", "Low Birth Weight", Parameters!VerylowBirthWeight.Value(0) <> "0", "Very Low Birth Weight")
```

The problem is that regardless of the setting of the parameters, 'Normal Birth Weight' is displayed.
So, by default, NormalBirthWeight is set to 0 and 1.  In the dataset, when I want only the Normal weights this bit is set to 1.
Regardless of the dataset shown, the text is always 'Normal Birth Weight'.

I tried using:

```
=Switch(Parameters!NormalBirthWeight.Value(0) = "1", "Normal Birth Weight", Parameters!LowBirthWeight.Value(0) = "1", "Low Birth Weight", Parameters!VerylowBirthWeight.Value(0) = "1", "Very Low Birth Weight")
```

But the same result occurs, the text Normal Birth Weight is always shown.

Is there a way in VB to use 'IN' and a list of like this:

```
Parameters!NormalBirthWeight.Value IN ("1", "0")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an expression like this to perform an `IN` in SSRS:

```
=IIf(
Array.IndexOf(Parameters!NormalBirthWeight.Value,"1")>-1,"Normal Birth Weight",
""
)
```

The above expression checks if `"1"` is selected in the parameter. If so returns `"Normal Birth Weight"` otherwise returns an empty string, `""`.

If you want to use a `Switch` statement be careful since the first expression evaluated to `true` will return the value to the whole expression:

```
=Switch(
Array.IndexOf(Parameters!NormalBirthWeight.Value,"1")>-1,"Normal Birth Weight",
Array.IndexOf(Parameters!LowBirthWeight.Value,"1")>-1,"Low Birth Weight",
Array.IndexOf(Parameters!VerylowBirthWeight.Value,"1")>-1,"Very Low Birth Weight"
)
```

In this case if NormalBirthWeight parameter has "1" selected or set by default, it will always return `"Normal Birth Weight"`.

Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can **JOIN** all of your selected parameters into one string and then look for the desired value from that string using **INSTR**. The pipes (|) are used to ensure that **1** isn't found when **10** is the only value.

```
=Switch(INSTR("|" & Join(Parameters!NormalBirthWeight.Label, "|") & "|", "|1|") > 0 ...
```